# Has anyone implemented split screen support for iOS in Xamarin Forms and if so how did they go about it?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I would love to be able to implement this feature. Is it possible with the current version and are there any examples or documentation on how to do this?

Comment: It seems Xamarin.forms does not support split screen so far. You have to use native code to implement this feature.

Comment: Do you know if that is on the roadmap?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. You can create a Feature request in Github.